# Custom Hamburger icon with Navigation Component

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

I'm using new Navigation Component in my project. I created a custom Toolbar which will keep the Title in the centre even when having navigation drawer.

This is how my toolbar looks now.
[image]
[image]

I'm trying to put a custom hamburger and back icon there(basically i need **white icons**).

I've tried

`dataBinding.appBarHome.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_hamburger));`

`getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_hamburger));`

None of it is working. if want to see any specific part of my code, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it just because of style or them,
Just try with bellow style

```
ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar
```

When every you choose dark action bar then default icon color should be white and when you select an action bar then it will be the black icon

So just replace style in your manifest or style.xml

Comment: This is working. I used ```Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar```. This makes the default icon colour as white. Is there any way to change these icon?

Comment: Yes, you can set calling setNavigationIcon() in your toolbar instance.